# Creating a custom gate (given by a matrix) more efficiently

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction, matrix-representation

I have the following gate (as represented by its matrix) on $4$ qubits which I hope to use in an error-detection code

$$M=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Naively, it is possible to make this gate using the following configuration of generalized toffoli gates and $X$ gates:

[image: Naive way]

However, this is already past what is feasible to do on current machines. My question is: Is there a better way to implement $M$ or has previous research been done to create gates whose matrix representations consist solely of $0$s and $1$s. This is not the only gate that I could implement that would serve my purposes (in fact, there are $(4!)^4=24^4=331176$ matrices that would work), but this is the 'simplest' one (simplest as in it presents the most symmetry).

Comment: To the commentor before, when I tried to use the qiskit circuit decomposition (found https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.extensions.UnitaryGate.html) I got "Not able to generate a subcircuit for a 4-qubit unitary"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look carefully, the circuit just flips the least significant qubit if the parity of the two most significant qubits is one. So, using qiskit:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)

qc.cx(2, 0)
qc.cx(3, 0)

print(qc)
U = Operator(qc).data
print(U.real)
---
Output:
     ┌───┐┌───┐
q_0: ┤ X ├┤ X ├
     └─┬─┘└─┬─┘
q_1: ──┼────┼──
       │    │  
q_2: ──■────┼──
            │  
q_3: ───────■──
               
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia and the book Quantum Information and Quantum Computation have discussed the question of universal quantum gates, say, what kind of sets of small gates can compose any large gates. In both cases, they do not list all possible sets, but all listed sets contain some sort of phase gate, and so the imaginary number 'i' is always contained. So, I do not think just 0 and 1 are enough.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Universal_quantum_gates